# Getting duplicates in csv from a spider written in python

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler

I've created a spider that is collecting data as I expected.The only problem I'm facing at this moment is that the results are with lots of duplicates. However, I want to shake the duplicates off while writing results in csv:

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint():
    global writer
    outfile=open('Data.csv','w',newline='')
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Price"])
    address = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/stores/"
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"level0")]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"level0")]/@href')[0]
        Layer2(href)

def Layer2(address):
    global writer
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"amshopby-cat")]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        Endpoint(href)

def Endpoint(address):
    global writer
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@class="product-info"]')
    for title in titles:
        Name = title.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"h3")]/a[@title]/text()')[0]
        Price = title.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()')[0]
        metco=(Name,Price)
        print(metco)
        writer.writerow(metco)

Startpoint()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `csv` module to wrtie csv files. Specifying the extension is enough. Thus, turning your code into

```
import requests
from lxml import html

delimiter = ";"
file_name = 'data.csv'

def Startpoint():
    address = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/stores/"
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"level0")]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"level0")]/@href')[0]
        Layer2(href)

def Layer2(address):
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"amshopby-cat")]')
    for title in titles:
        href = title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        Endpoint(href)

def Endpoint(address):
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@class="product-info"]')
    for title in titles:
        Name = title.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"h3")]/a[@title]/text()')[0]
        Price = title.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()')[0]
        metco=(Name,Price)
        print(metco)
        with open(file_name,'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(delimiter.join(metco).encode('utf8') + '\n')

with open(file_name,'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(delimiter.join(["Product Name", "Price"])+'\n')
Startpoint()
```

should do the trick. Note the `.encode('utf8')` part which prevents your writing process from `UnicodeEncodeError`. Furthermore, note the arguments `'w'` and `'a'` used in the `open` function. While the first means "write", the second means "append". However, even if from an heuristic point of view, this code works, it is far from being "well" thought.

Comment: Thanks Tnerual for your answer. You are very near to what i was expecting. Encoding doesn't work in this case so I discarded that line. All the results are now in the csv file but they are positioned not in the separate columns but in a single column delimited by comma. Can you make it in two columns? Thanks. Here is the link to that output: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/okb7hxocmv5lbax/data.csv?dl=0"

Comment: @SMth80 you can try to change the variable whose name is `delimiter`. Changing the semi-colon `";"` for a comma `","`.

Comment: It works but faces issues when it sees the price exceeding thousand cause you know thousand is written like this "1,000". So, your code creates a separate column as soon as it meets ",". Anyways, I've fixed it and rewritten the rectified one in my first post. Could you tell me how can I shake off duplicates while writing in csv. Thanks.

Comment: @SMth80 This is exactly the reason why i prefer not to use a comma as delimiter. Since it looks like you use excel to visualise your csv file, note that you can actually tell it what to consider as delimiter. It works directly with comma because it is (often) the default one. To control duplicates, you can create a list in which each element to write goes only if not already present. You would then have to iter over this list to write the content. Furthermore, the UnicodeEncodeError does not occur in python3.+, I.e. The version of python that you use.

Comment: @SMth80 Furthermore, note you must not change the title of your question substantially so as to get a completely new related answer. I answered your question, my answer does what you need, you declare it as the correct one. If you have something else to ask, you create/open a new question.

Comment: Thanks Tnerual for everything.